Why is Jest plain javascript unit test trying to read NextJS?
I added Jest to make some unit tests of plain javascript classes.
They were working, but I added some more code and now I tried to execute the tests and got this:
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /home/jorgee/Desktop/Proyectos/WPro/nhcom-fe/src/pages/_app.tsx:22
        return (<lavanda_1.Lavanda pageProps={pageProps} intl={app_1.intlConfig} theme={chakra_1.theme} disableSeo>
                ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

      1 | import { useMemo } from 'react';
      2 | import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
    > 3 | import { urql } from '../../../pages/_app';
        | ^
      4 | import { getDrawerFooterMenu, getDrawerMenu, getFooterMenu, getHeaderMenu } from '../queries/menus';
      5 | import { DrawerFooterMenuQuery, DrawerMenuQuery, FooterMenuQuery, HeaderMenuQuery } from '../wordpress-schema';
      6 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (modules/wordpress/hooks/use-site-menus.tsx:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (modules/wordpress/hooks/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (modules/wordpress/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (modules/wordpress/queries/neighborhoodQuery.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (infrastructure/wordpress/ResourceTypeToQueryMapper.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (infrastructure/wordpress/GraphQLClient.ts:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (infrastructure/wordpress/WPApiProxy.test.ts:3:1)

Why is Jest even trying to read NextJS? The tests are testing a javascript class object, unrelated to React or NextJS
EDIT: I traced this issue down to using aliased imports like import Something from "@modules/something"
